# java implementation of excel price,yield functions

Tags: java, excel

Was wondering if anyone can point me to an open source java quant library that provides implementation for Excel Price and Yield functions.

Thanks,
Tapasvi

Comment: Not sure if there is a library that uses the exact same calculation, but Excel help gives you the exact algorithm used to run the calculation so it should be fairly easy to replicate.

Comment: Strata is a new Java library for market risk, which may be of interest (Disclaimer, I am an author) - http://strata.opengamma.io/

Comment: @JodaStephen Is there any version of strata available compatible with java 1.7??

Comment: Strata has always been for Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel PRICE function is a simple sum of discounted cash flows, discounted assuming a flat zero rate discounting curve. It is documented here: [Excel Help / PRICE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/price-HP005209219.aspx).

I wrote a small Java version of the function, which I am posting below. The Java version just takes a "time to maturity" and does not support different daycountings, while the Excel PRICE function takes a settlement date and maturity date and supports different daycountings. However, you can attribute for the different daycountings by converting the coupon. Note also that the Excel function has a strange hardcoded notional of 100 in front of the coupon.

An Excel sheet benchmarking the two implementations can be [downloaded here](http://www.obba.info/tutorial/priceandyield/). The sheet requires ["Obba"](http://www.obba.info/).

The Excel YIELD function is just a Newton solver applied to the PRICE function, see [Excel Help / YIELD](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/yield-HP005209345.aspx). A Java implementation of the Newton solver can be found at [finmath.net](http://www.finmath.net).

```
/*
 * Created on 07.04.2012
 */

/**
 * This class implements some functions as static class methods.
 *
 * (c) Copyright 2012 Christian Fries.
 *
 * @author Christian Fries
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class SpreadsheetFunctions {

    /**
     * Re-implementation of the Excel PRICE function (a rather primitive bond price formula).
     * The reimplementation is not exact, because this function does not consider daycount conventions.
     * We assume we have (int)timeToMaturity/frequency future periods and the running period has
     * an accrual period of timeToMaturity - frequency * ((int)timeToMaturity/frequency).
     * 
     * @param timeToMaturity The time to maturity.
     * @param coupon Coupon payment.
     * @param yield Yield (discount factor, using frequency: 1/(1 + yield/frequency).
     * @param redemption Redemption (notional repayment).
     * @param frequency Frequency (1,2,4).
     * @return price Clean price.
     */
    public static double price(
            double timeToMaturity,
            double coupon,
            double yield,
            double redemption,
            int frequency)
    {
        double price = 0.0;

        if(timeToMaturity > 0) {
            price += redemption;
        }

        double paymentTime = timeToMaturity;
        while(paymentTime > 0) {
            price += coupon/frequency;

            // Discount back
            price = price / (1.0 + yield / frequency);
            paymentTime -= 1.0 / frequency;
        }

        // Accrue running period
        double accrualPeriod = 0.0-paymentTime; // amount of running period which lies in the past (before settlement)
        price *= Math.pow(1.0 + yield / frequency, accrualPeriod*frequency);
        price -= coupon/frequency * accrualPeriod*frequency;

        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml). It's a free/open source library for quantitative finance.

Comment: Using QuantLib from Java requires going through SWIG. I am afraid performance may be an issue there. Do you have prior experience with SWIG?

Comment: Sorry, I have no prior experience of SWIG.