# Cannot run excel function from MS Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

We are migrating an MS Access 2003 app from Office 2003 to Office 2010 (and WinXP => Win7) and have run into a problem trying to run the [Excel Yield function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/yield-HP005209345.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) from MS Access. The current code to do this (which works on XP / Office 2003) looks like this:

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
objExcel.RegisterXLL objExcel.Application.LibraryPath & "\ANALYSIS\ANALYS32.XLL"
dblYield = objExcel.Run("Yield", dteTDate, rstSec.Fields(2), dblRate / 100, dblPricePaid, rstSec.Fields(7), rstSec.Fields(4), rstSec.Fields(6))
```

The code errors on the final line and gives the following error:

*Run-time error '1004':
Cannot run the macro 'Yield'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.*

I've tried a few things, including specifically adding and registering the Analysis Toolpack using the following code:

```
objExcel.RegisterXLL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\Analysis\ATPVBAEN.XLA"
```

But I get the same error.

I'm thinking at the moment that the problem may be down to maybe needing to create a macro enabled workbook, or perhaps it's some Win7 / Office 2010 security setting that I am unfamiliar with.

The only potential solution I can come up with at the moment is to create a COM interop .net assembly that wraps an Excel instance exposing the Yield function. However I'd prefer a different solution because to go the COM interop route I'd have to get admin rights, then to deploy I'd have to register the dll on the end users machine, in addition I'd most probably run into the same error in .net as in MS Access.

Finally there is a .net project to recreate a number of the [Excel financial functions in an F# assembly](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FinancialFunctions). Unfortunately the Yield function is not one of the re-implemented functions.

I'd very much appreciate any advice on this,

Cheers,

Jamie

Comment: "macros disabled"? What is the name of the file? Try to save it as a ".xlsm" file (new Excel format with macros), and make sure that under _File - Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings... - Macro Settings_ you have enabled the macros in this workbook to run.

Comment: Hi Floris, there is no actual Excel file, only the Excel.Application created in memory. Maybe I have to actually use an Excel file as you describe, and force the users to change their macros settings as per the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421843/excel-vba-enabling-macro-settings

Comment: Ah - this is actually a more interesting question than I thought... Does your Access file have macros enabled? Why are you using an Excel macro if there is no Excel file - why not use an Access macro? The link you gave shows the equation - pretty simple to implement directly in Access. Would probably get a significant performance boost from not having to open an instance of Excel...

Comment: Hi Floris, yes Access has macros enabled, the code errors at the line where Yield is called. I am using an instance of Excel because we just need to use the Yield function, hence this was an easier option. As for implementing the Yield function in Access, I have done some investigation into that and found that others had some issues with how detailed the MS specification is as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801859/net-implementation-of-excel-yield-function/801896#801896 so there would be added risk/work if I were to reimplement and test an existing Excel function.

Comment: I might tackle the proper answer to that earlier question - it's something I enjoy doing. If I'm successful I will post an answer here and there. I'm afraid I'm not a user of Access so it would be hard for me to debug the issue you are having with calling Excel. But maybe someone else will give you that solution. Then you'll have two...

Comment: If you have Access+ SQL Server, then you can do all without Excel, or use the latter as simpe task notes for your future work ?

Comment: Hi jacouh, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the function we need (Yield) is defined in Excel and not available elsewhere (unless we reimplement it). For that reason unfortunately, we need to use Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, the way I solved (worked around) it was to use an external workbook in which I had the yield formula in a cell, referencing a bunch of cells containing the yield parameters. I then replace the parameters via my Access vba function, force the worksheet to recalculate the formula and return it to my Access database.